# Polymer dom-if not re-firing

Tags: polymer, dom-if

I have been having problems with my Polymer 2 app, I first through it was the routing but I found that after hitting this page and the Dom-if fires when navigating back to the page it is not re-firing.

EG,

If I am on url/matters/6719 it displays the details page, but if I click the back button and go to url/matters the dom-if is not being hit again and its still showing me the details page,

It also happens when using my navigation selector which is set up like the PWA starter kit.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-route.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="Matters/matter-list.html">
<link rel="import" href="MatParties/matparty-list.html">
<link rel="lazy-import" href="Matters/matter-detail.html">


<dom-module id="my-matters">


  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;

        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:matter_id" data="{{routeData}}" tail="{{subroute}}">
      <app-route route="{{subroute}}" pattern="/matparties/:this_page" data="{{pageData}}"></app-route>
    </app-route>

    <div class="card">
        <template is="dom-if" if="[[_subidIsDefined(pageData.this_page)]]">
            <matparty-list linkedmatpartyid="[[pageData.this_page]]"></matparty-list>
          </template>
<template is="dom-if" if="[[!_subidIsDefined(pageData.this_page)]]">
      <template is="dom-if" if="[[!_idIsDefined(routeData.matter_id)]]">
        <matter-list></matter-list>
      </template>
      <template is="dom-if" if="[[_idIsDefined(routeData.matter_id)]]">
        <matter-detail linkedmatterid="[[routeData.matter_id]]"></matter-detail>
      </template>
</template>

  </template>

  <script>
    class Matters extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-matters'; }


      _subidIsDefined(subid) {

        //There are probably ways to optimize this
        if (subid) {

          return true;
        }

        return false;
      }

      _idIsDefined(id) {

        //There are probably ways to optimize this
        if (id) {
          return true;
        }

        return false;
      }

    }
    window.customElements.define(Matters.is, Matters);
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the pattern? Normally the pattern should respect the url pattern.... in your case "url/matters/6719"

Since you have defined the pattern="/matparties/:this_page" on the router and  **matparties** is != 'matters' in 'url/matters/6719' that could generate the error. I don't know if you have defined a base url that generate also some issues on this regards.

So the url should be matparties/6719 to match the pattern and resolve into the dom-if

Comment: I am putting console logs in the functions that get called by the Dom-if's and the just aren't being hit when clicking the browser back button